# Get an email notification or a trigger when new public image in GCP (windows, rhel etc) is out?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-image-search

Is there any method in GCP where we can get an email notification when new public image (windows, rhel etc) is out?
We are creating golden images every month and was wondering if there's any notifications system in GCP where we can get an email when GCP publish its public images once a month.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, one of the ways that you could possibly look at is to use the `gcloud compute images...` CLI command to get the details.

You could write a script that does a diff across runs (scheduled at a gap of say 24 hours) and if there is a diff, notify the team via email.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the only solution today.

Answer (score 0):

You can always subscribe to this [group](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-image-notifications) to receive an email notification for any updates in GCP
Images.

Comment: That group has been deprecated as of December 2021. https://groups.google.com/g/gce-image-notifications/c/VaXS-6Qb3TQ

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).